# Thread dump showing incorrect thread state

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to diagnose a production issue. I set up a little test program on Mac OS Lion that launches 10 threads (using Executors.newCachedThreadPool() which all call MUTEX.wait(), in a synchronized block)

Then I do a kill -3 to get a thread dump, and I see all of my threads showing BLOCKED.
Shouldn't these all be WAITING?

The code is something like this, (forgive the code smells introduced for brevity)

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final Object MUTEX = new Object();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        synchronized(MUTEX) {
         MUTEX.wait();
}  }   }}
```

At this point all threads should be in the WAITING state but in fact a thread dump shows all are BLOCKED

Comment: Can you add a trace of one of the threads because I have not see ExecutorService use `wait()`, instead it uses the `park()`?

Comment: The Executor is not calling wait, my code is calling wait.

Comment: Can you post the piece of code that your threads execute?

Comment: Can you also post the thread dump, for at one or two threads?

Comment: Are the threads in the `BLOCKED` state at `synchronized(MUTEX) {` or `MUTEX.wait();`?

Comment: They are BLOCED on the MUTEX.wait().

Comment: The first thread that acquires `MUTEX` in the `synchronized` block reaches `MUTEX.wait()`. I expect that the other threads be `BLOCKED` at the synchronized statement, because they have to acquire `MUTEX`.

Comment: Please note, I have asked to close this question. It is not working as I described. I did not include some scaffolding code in the above, and that turned out to be the cause. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: It would nice if you could update the question with the missing information so that this Q&A does not mislead future readers.

Comment: Hi Reprogrammer. If they decide not to kill the posting, I will try to get something up there to explain the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your threads are waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method, their status is `BLOCKED`.

A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in the `BLOCKED` state and a thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in the `WAITING` state.

See below for more details about the difference between `BLOCKED` and `WAITING`:

From the JavaDoc of [BLOCKED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED):

> Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock. A thread
>   in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a
>   synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after
>   calling `Object.wait`.

From the JavaDoc of [WAITING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING):

> A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to perform
>   a particular action. For example, a thread that has called
>   `Object.wait()` on an object is waiting for another thread to call
>   `Object.notify()` or `Object.notifyAll()` on that object. A thread that
>   has called `Thread.join()` is waiting for a specified thread to
>   terminate.

Comment: I think that is a bit ambiguous. I think that is referring to threads that were already in a WAIT state, which were awakened by a notifyAll, but cannot move because one of the notified threads already grabbed the lock. In contrast, when a thread calls wait(), before any notify occurs, I believe it should go into WAITING state, not BLOCKED

Comment: So clearly from the JavaDoc of WAITING, that is the state I should be in. I am not waiting for access to a synchronized block, i am waiting as a result of a call to wait()! So why does my thread dump show BLOCKED?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, do you agree? Or am I missing something? I mean the points you have stated are true, but they do not answer my question, they strengthen it.

Comment: If you provide more information, e.g., the thread dumps, we might be able to give a more specific answer. Given the information that you provided, all I can say is that according to the Javadoc of `BLOCKED`, a thread could become `BLOCKED` after calling `Object.wait()`.